# Squid "system returned (13) Permission denied"

Tags: squid, httpd

I can get to a site form my Squid server directly using lynx `http://my-URL` , ie not using squid as the proxy, just  to prove  the connectivity exists. Lynx connects fine to the site - its a Weblogic portal

When I try the same site from client with the squid machine as a proxy I get a squid error indicating that the destination site refused the connection from Squid.

The squid server is a RHEL5.5 server.

The error is something like

```
The following error was encountered:  Connection Failed

The systen returned: (13) Permission denied
```

The squid access.log just indicates a TCP_MISS. It's as if the destination site knows its been accessed by squid and is not allowing ?

Comment: Any relevant error from cache.log? Also, what is the HTTP code printed in the access.log near TCP_MISS?

Comment: Resolved now thanks , It turned out to be SElinux.  Can anyone tell me how I can close a post without an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved now - it turned out to be an SElinux issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to toy around with your squid ACL rules. I bet you that's the issue in there. Hopefully your squid.conf is well commented so you can figure it out easily enough. I suspect you'll want to take a look at ACL rules that refer to your LAN and HTTP connections.